# Cannot import name SetDefaultColoring

Tags: python, android, linux, git

When i am trying to sync repo :

`repo init -u git://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b lineage-17.1`

its getting error like :

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'color'`

and then after trying installing color module `pip install color` or `pip3 install color`

i am stuck with this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/.repo/repo/main.py", line 48, in <module>
    from color import SetDefaultColoring
ImportError: cannot import name 'SetDefaultColoring'
```

Comment: try using `pip install colour`

Comment: error message still same after try `pip install colour`

Comment: Try it: git clone https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git

git+clone+https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git

Comment: I tried and it works with no errors. Is there any requirements to use `repo`? I think `git clone` should be better